# Applying jquery to first element of the list

Tags: jquery, html

Hi i followed this link but i cannot get the output:
[jQuery selector to find the first child in each of a set of elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740746/jquery-selector-to-find-the-first-child-in-each-of-a-set-of-elements).

I want to select first element of the list and make the fadein animation when i click the button having id "#add". I wrote code as follow but cant get the output. Please help.

### HTML

```
  <div class="panel-body" style="height: 400px;overflow-y: scroll;">

            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="list_entry">
                <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="add"><i class="icon-plus-sign"></i></button>
                </span>
            </div><br>


            <ul class="list-group" id="inlist">
                <li>something</li>
                <li>something1</li>
                <li>something2</li>
                <li>something3</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

### Jquery

```
 $("#add").live('click',function(){
 var li = $(this).parent().parent().next().find("li:eq(0)"); //how can i select first li
  li.animate(something);  
 });
```

Comment: $(this) only works inside a function and indicates the element that called the function, you cant just use it outside of a context...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#add').click(function(){
        $('#inlist li:first').fadeOut('slow').fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/zL7hhtec/2/)

Comment: thanks and how can i add this fade animation in jquery ajax complete. because first li comes after the ajax complete.

Comment: I found the answer. I added complete: function() {    } ..and inside it this animation. And It worked great. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

move the `eq` outside of the selector, its a jquery function:

```
$("#add").live('click',function(){
    var li = $(this).parent().parent().next().find("li").eq(0); //how can i select first li
    li.animate(something);  
});
```